# push view navigation Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm working in Sencha Touch framework, and want to design a navigation bar to push my additional views. However, I want to add either my `cardlayout` (eg: `xtype: 'mycard'` ) or a widget (eg: `xtype: 'my'`).
How can I push my existing view which is already defined as `Ext.define('MyProject.view.my', {//some deination})`. I tried the following code but unable to call in my `handler` function when the button pressed in navigation bar.
I'm absolutely unable to `push`any view as it is not working in my `handler` function, and unable to call the `view.push`.
How can I get my view and push as a navigation item?

**Tried Code for push some view:**

```
    //create the navigation view and add it into the Ext.Viewport
    var view = Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'navigationview',

        //we only give it one item by default, which will be the only item in the 'stack' when it loads
        items: [{
            //items can have titles
            title: 'Navigation View',
            padding: 10,

            //inside this first item we are going to add a button
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Push another view!',
                handler: function () {
                    //when someone taps this button, it will push another view into stack
                    view.push({
                        //this one also has a title
                        title: 'Second View',
                        padding: 10,

                        //once again, this view has one button
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Pop this view!',
                            handler: function () {
                                //and when you press this button, it will pop the current view (this) out of the stack
                                view.pop();
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
```

**My Code:**

```
    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'btn',
                        id: 'btn1',
                        scope: this,
                        handler: function(b, e) {
    //here I want to push my view named as xtype: 'my'
// my main viewport has the xtype: 'main' and  alias: 'widget.mypanel'
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What means 'push a view' ? Your question doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the view on the fly then add it to the view's items collection. I.e. in your event handler try to add

```
var view = Ext.create('MyProject.view.my', {});
this.add([view]);
```